# Prelude.!!: index too large (Haskell recursion based on access to previously calculated list elements.)

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I have such code in Haskell. It's filling in the list recursively. Some "i" parameters (every even except 0) are calculated based on previous calculations.

```
fillIn :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
fillIn max_val i list
  | i > max_val = list
  | i == 0 = ((function i):[]) ++ (fillIn max_val (i+1) list)
  | even i = (((list!!(i `div` 2)) + (i `div` 2)):[]) ++ (fillIn max_val (i+1) list)
  | otherwise = ((function i):[]) ++ (fillIn max_val (i+1) list)
```

It generates error: **Prelude.!!: index too large** when it tries to access list at 1 (*list!!1*). I don't know why because when it calculates `fillIn max_val 2 list` it has `fillIn max_val 1 list` done.
Do you know how I can fix it? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You check if `i > max_val`, but you never check if `list` is indeed long enough for each of your attempted indices to work.

Comment: Also, `(x:[]) ++ ...` is more simply written `x : ...`.

Comment: Personally, I would define this with something like `fillIn max_val list = map f (take max_val list) ++ drop max_val list where f = ...`

Comment: When asking about non-working code you've written, you should always explain what the code is *supposed* to do. It's really hard to say how to fix the problem when we don't know what you're expecting.

Comment: You folks, this is a fine question, retract your close votes immediately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty to re-write your code in a more *"conventional"* fashion, *(hopefully)* without
changing its meaning.

```
fillIn :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
fillIn max_val i list
    | i > max_val = list
    | i == 0 || odd i = f i: fillIn max_val (i + 1) list
    | even i = list !! (i `div` 2) + (i `div` 2): fillIn max_val (i + 1) list
```

It still looks like you took an imperative algorithm on arrays and squeezed it into Haskell, and
it is difficult to understand what the code is supposed to do. But I made a long guess that
possibly you meant for `list` to be an *"accumulator"* and for the function to be tail recursive.
I can then re-write it like this:

```
fillIn :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
fillIn max_val i list
    | i > max_val = list
    | i == 0 || odd i = fillIn max_val (i + 1) (f i                              : list)
    | even i          = fillIn max_val (i + 1) (list !! (i `div` 2) + (i `div` 2): list)
```

— And it will actually work.

I am still not sure what it computes. A recursive sequence of some kind. If you tell me what your
goal is, maybe we can devise a more *"idiomatic"* version.